# How to configure SASL enabled memcached username and password on mac

Tags: memcached, sasl, spymemcached, memcachedb

I installed memcached version 1.4.34 on my mac using homebrew. I wanted to configure a username and password to enable SASL support when interacting with memcache. Can you point me the right direction for this?
Ran below command to install memcache on mac.

```
brew install memcached --enable-sasl-pwdb
```

Above command installed memcache with sasl support.

```
echo "mech_list: plain" > memcached.conf
echo "myuser:mypass" > /tmp/memcached-sasl-db
export MEMCACHED_SASL_PWDB=/tmp/memcached-sasl-db
export SASL_CONF_PATH=`pwd`/memcached.conf
memcached -u myuser -m 1024 -p 8010 -S -B binary -vvv

Initialized SASL.
```

Now when I connect via memcache client it says  Password verification failed on the terminal.

```
mech:  ``PLAIN'' with 15 bytes of data
INFO: User <myuser@mylocal-macbook.local> failed to authenticate
SASL (severity 2): Password verification failed
sasl result code:  -20
Unknown sasl response:  -20
```

Here's the java code I'm using:

```
public class MemcacheTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThreshold", "10");

    AuthDescriptor ad = new AuthDescriptor(new String[] { "PLAIN" },
            new PlainCallbackHandler(
                    "myuser", "mypass"));

    ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
            .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY)
            .setAuthWaitTime(10000)
            .setOpTimeout(10000)
            .setShouldOptimize(true)
            .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build();

    List<InetSocketAddress> servers = AddrUtil
            .getAddresses("localhost:8010");
    MemcachedClient cacheClient = null;
    try {
        cacheClient = new MemcachedClient(connFactory, servers);
        cacheClient.set("foo", 50000, "bar");
        System.out.println("Value: " + cacheClient.get("foo"));
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here are my intellij logs:

```
    2017-02-23 15:19:04.223 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnection due to exception handling a memcached operation on {QA sa=localhost/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}. This may be due to an authentication failure.
OperationException: SERVER: Auth failure.
    at net.spy.memcached.protocol.BaseOperationImpl.handleError(BaseOperationImpl.java:192)
    at net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.OperationImpl.finishedPayload(OperationImpl.java:204)
    at net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.SASLBaseOperationImpl.finishedPayload(SASLBaseOperationImpl.java:98)
    at net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.OperationImpl.readPayloadFromBuffer(OperationImpl.java:196)
    at net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.OperationImpl.readFromBuffer(OperationImpl.java:139)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.readBufferAndLogMetrics(MemcachedConnection.java:861)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:840)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReadsAndWrites(MemcachedConnection.java:720)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:683)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:436)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:1446)
```

Comment: @Koen  do you have any pointers on this?

Comment: @rastko do you have any pointers on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yay! I got the issue. Couch base client automatically adds hostname at the end of the username. In my case when I set the username as myuser:mypassword but when I pass myuser in my java code, memcacheclient pass that information as myuser@mylocalhost-mac and that's where the mismatch was happening. To solve that I added the complete username with local host of the ssl db.

Instead of below line

```
echo "myuser:mypass" > /tmp/memcached-sasl-db
```

is replaced by

```
echo "myuser@mylocalhostMacBook-Pro-2.local:mypass" > /tmp/memcached-sasl-db
```

Now in java client I just pass myuser and client add the hostname automatically.

Comment: Fxxking cool! I've spend whole night for this, even thought change linux to mac, and finnaly got here when I am totally despaired, thank you!